# What is appropriate HttpClient Design for Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I am a iOS programmer (not very experienced). I usually create a HttpClient.class for all other class to use. Like:

```
@implementation HttpClient
-(NSString*)getGetResponse :(NSString*)url{
    //do all http get request work
    return result;
}
@end
```

Then I can call this `getGetResponse:` anywhere in my project to do the http get work.

```
NSString *result = [httpClient getGetResponse:@"http://www.example.com/api"]
```

But Android request network running in class extends AsyncTask.Like:

```
 public class HttpTask extends AsyncTask<String,String, String > {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //network code here
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

This makes me confused. How do I do the same thing like the objective-c code does above?(return the result back to caller)

Comment: Most Android developers currently use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for interacting with APIs, or [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) for other HTTP tasks. I don't recommend AsyncTasks for most of this type of work.

Comment: Thank you, I will research for Retrofit and OkHttp.

Comment: @Tanis.7x Most Android developers do not use retrofit or other libraries.  Some do, but far from most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.  HTTP calls need to happen asycnhronously.  Instead of returning a result, forcing the thread to wait, you need to do any processing that requires the result in onPostExecute.

Comment: Thank you for replying. What you mean is that I have to implement a HttpTask class in every class which needs to do network work?

Comment: Yes.  Or a single class that takes a result callback, but you're still doing a new class that way, just not having to make the http call each time.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are right. But don't you think this design is so unreasonable or redundant?

Comment: Not at all.  The idea of having an asynchronous call return synchronously is horribly inefficient.  Either you're holding up all processing on the thread, or you're just making the threading call higher up the callchain in which case you're doing the same thing but android is more up front about it.

Comment: I agree with your idea now. I do think the design I used to make is not good.